# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bootstrapValidator is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy validando  un campo de un formulario con Bootstrap validator pero tengo un error que me indica que "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bootstrapValidator is not a function", agregue todas las librerías pero tampoco 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<form id="enviaConfirmada" name="enviaConfirmada" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lblFecha" class="control-label col-sm-3">Fecha</label>
    <div class='input-group col-sm-8'>
      <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
      </span>
      <input type='text' id="txtFecha" name="txtfecha" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
    </div>
    <label for="lblFecha" class="control-label col-sm-1"></label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lblNumvendedor" class="control-label col-sm-3">N° de vendedor</label>
    <div class='input-group col-sm-8'>
      <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span>
      </span>
      <input type='text' id="txtVendedor" name="txtVendedor" maxlength="4" onkeypress="ponerMayusculas(this);" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <label for="lblNumvendedor" class="control-label col-sm-1"></label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-9"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <!--<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Buscar" id="btn-enviar" class="btn btn-success" />-->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnGuarda">Guardar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

el formulario lo mando con un button ya que uso ajax, mas o menos tengo asi algo con mi codigo para el HTML donde se encuentra el form

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title></title>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#enviaConfirmada').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'Este valor no es valido',
        feedbackIcons: {
          valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
          invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
          validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
          txtVendedor: {
            validators: {
              notEmpty: {
                message: 'El # de vendedor es requerido'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- modal -->
  <div class="modal fade " id="modalVendedor" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog " role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h5 class="modal-title">:: Estatus de solicitudes ::</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <!-- div muestra formulario -->
          <div id="muestraFormulario">
            <!-- formulario -->
            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i> Ingrese número de vendedor</div>
            <form id="enviaConfirmada" name="enviaConfirmada" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lblSolicitud" class="control-label col-sm-3">N° de solicitud</label>
                <div class='input-group col-sm-8'>
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
                  </span>
                  <input type='text' id="txtNumsolicitud" name="txtNumsolicitud" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
                </div>
                <label for="lblSolicitud" class="control-label col-sm-1"></label>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lblFecha" class="control-label col-sm-3">Fecha</label>
                <div class='input-group col-sm-8'>
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
                  </span>
                  <input type='text' id="txtFecha" name="txtfecha" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
                </div>
                <label for="lblFecha" class="control-label col-sm-1"></label>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lblNumvendedor" class="control-label col-sm-3">N° de vendedor</label>
                <div class='input-group col-sm-8'>
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span>
                  </span>
                  <input type='text' id="txtVendedor" name="txtVendedor" maxlength="4" onkeypress="ponerMayusculas(this);" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <label for="lblNumvendedor" class="control-label col-sm-1"></label>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-9"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <!--<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Buscar" id="btn-enviar" class="btn btn-success" />-->
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnGuarda">Guardar</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
            <!-- fin formulario -->
          </div>
          <!-- div muestra formulario -->
          <div id="carga"></div>
          <div id="resultado"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
          <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalNo" data-whatever="no">No</button>-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- modal -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ¿Qué biblioteca estás usando para `bootstrapValidator`?¿Podrías incluir todos los errores de la consola?¿seguro que has incluído todas las bibliotecas?

Comment: uso la librería Bootstrap validator, lo que borre es un icono que no encuentra pero nada de importancia

Comment: ¿Ésta: https://plugins.jquery.com/bootstrapValidator/? Prueba a poner `BootstrapValidator` (con la B en mayúscula)

Comment: si estan son las librerias: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />.........
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" />.........

  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>.........
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>.........
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>

Comment: Ok, he copiado todo tu código y me funciona bien en local después de apuntar jQuery y Bootstrap.js a CDN: cuando escribo algo en el nº de vendedor y lo borro, me sale un mensaje de error: "El # de vendedor es requerido" en rojo (ese es el resultado esperado, ¿no?).

Comment: @Alvaro Montoro ok ya funciono, pero ahora cuando esta vació el campo no hace la validación,  envía el campo vació ¿Cómo le puedo hacer para que valide si ya todos los campos son correctos o están llenos que envié el form?

Comment: ¿cómo se envía el formulario? Si cambio el botón de `type="button"` a `type="submit"` funciona sin problemas (es decir, me da fallo si los campos están vacíos o con errores)

Comment: Esta pregunta debería cerrarse porque el problema es debido a un error que ya no ocurre. Aparte, la nueva pregunta (en los comentarios) ha sido [formulada en un nuevo post](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6164/problemas-al-validar-formulario), que es más completo que éste y ha obtenido respuestas válidas.

Comment: @Alvaro Montoro ya habia marcado respuesta pero la borraron

Answer (score 1):

Esa libreria de acuerdo a la página que estas enlazando de cdnjs funciona con formValidation.

http://formvalidation.io/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en el orden:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Como puedes ver primero tratas de jalar el plugin de validaciones antes de jquery, basta con invertir el órden

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" />
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#enviaConfirmada').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'Este valor no es valido',
        feedbackIcons: {
          valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
          invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
          validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
          txtVendedor: {
            validators: {
              notEmpty: {
                message: 'El # de vendedor es requerido'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>


  <!-- modal -->
  <div class="  " id="modalVendedor" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog " role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h5 class="modal-title">:: Estatus de solicitudes ::</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <!-- div muestra formulario -->
          <div id="muestraFormulario">
            <!-- formulario -->
            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i> Ingrese número de vendedor</div>
            <form id="enviaConfirmada" name="enviaConfirmada" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lblSolicitud" class="control-label col-sm-3">N° de solicitud</label>
                <div class='input-group col-sm-8'>
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
                  </span>
                  <input type='text' id="txtNumsolicitud" name="txtNumsolicitud" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
                </div>
                <label for="lblSolicitud" class="control-label col-sm-1"></label>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lblFecha" class="control-label col-sm-3">Fecha</label>
                <div class='input-group col-sm-8'>
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
                  </span>
                  <input type='text' id="txtFecha" name="txtfecha" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
                </div>
                <label for="lblFecha" class="control-label col-sm-1"></label>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lblNumvendedor" class="control-label col-sm-3">N° de vendedor</label>
                <div class='input-group col-sm-8'>
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span>
                  </span>
                  <input type='text' id="txtVendedor" name="txtVendedor" maxlength="4" onkeypress="ponerMayusculas(this);" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <label for="lblNumvendedor" class="control-label col-sm-1"></label>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-9"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <!--<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Buscar" id="btn-enviar" class="btn btn-success" />-->
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnGuarda">Guardar</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
            <!-- fin formulario -->
          </div>
          <!-- div muestra formulario -->
          <div id="carga"></div>
          <div id="resultado"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
          <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalNo" data-whatever="no">No</button>-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```