# problemas al validar formulario

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap

Tengo un formulario que envía información a otra pagina web para hacer una operación sobre una BD, pero estoy tratando de que primero valide el form para que no envie campos vacios a la BD, la validacion ya la tengo pero no he podido hacer para que primero valide y si no hay campos vacios envie la informacion a la BD, ya que actualmente envia aun cuando esta la validacion pero se debe a que tengo un js que tiene un evento click en donde se procesa el form a traves de ajax a la otra pagina y no se como hacer para primero valide y luego procese, haciendo pruebas comente la funcion click y ya valida tal ves tenga que ocupar otro evento pero no se cual?, este es mi codigo:

```js
    $('#btnGuarda').click(function () {        
        
        var cargando = $("#carga").html("<center><img class='img-responsive'  src='../imagenes/loading.gif'/><center>");

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../statussol/procesaConfirmada.vbhtml',
            data: $('#enviaConfirmada').serialize(),
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#muestraFormulario").hide();
                cargando.show().fadeIn();
            },
            success: function (e) {
                cargando.hide();                
                $('#resultado').hide().html("<blockquote style='background: #f9f9f9; border-left: 10px solid #ccc;   margin: 1.5em 10px;  padding: 0.5em 10px;'> <p></p><p style='color:green'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle'></i> ¡ Operación exitosa !</p><p></p> </blockquote>").fadeIn(500);
                $('#resultado').html(e);
            }
        });
    });
/* VALIDACION A MI INPUT DEL FOMULARIO*/
    $('#enviaConfirmada').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'Este valor no es valido',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            txtVendedor: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'El # de vendedor es requerido'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

mi formulario

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title></title>

  <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="../css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/scriptsConfirma.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/validate.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- div muestra formulario -->
  <div id="muestraFormulario">
    <!-- formulario -->
    <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i> Ingrese número</div>
    <form id="enviaConfirmada" name="enviaConfirmada" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lblSolicitud" class="control-label col-sm-3">N° de solicitud</label>
        <div class='input-group col-sm-8'>
          <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
          </span>
          <input type='text' id="txtNumsolicitud" name="txtNumsolicitud" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
        </div>
        <label for="lblSolicitud" class="control-label col-sm-1"></label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lblFecha" class="control-label col-sm-3">Fecha</label>
        <div class='input-group col-sm-8'>
          <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
          </span>
          <input type='text' id="txtFecha" name="txtfecha" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
        </div>
        <label for="lblFecha" class="control-label col-sm-1"></label>
      </div>
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label">N° de vendedor</label>

      <div class="col-md-7">
        <input type='text' id="txtVendedor" name="txtVendedor" maxlength="4" onkeypress="ponerMayusculas(this);" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-9"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnGuarda">Guardar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <!-- fin formulario -->
  </div>
  <!-- div muestra formulario -->
  <div id="carga"></div>
  <div id="resultado"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Elimine mi respuesta porque creo que coloque otro boostrap-validator.

Comment: @Wilfredo P pero algo parecido a lo que estoy resolviendo, no la hubieses borrado

Comment: Por esto era por lo que te preguntaba en el otro post para que compartieses el código de cómo se enviaba el formulario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tengo un formulario que envía información a otra pagina web para hacer una operación

No. No tienes un formulario que envía información... y ese es el verdadero problema que hay en el código: **el formulario nunca se envía y, por tanto, nunca llega a validarse**.

El plugin de validación comprueba cuando se ha enviado el formulario, es decir, cuando el evento `submit` se lanza. Y eso no ocurre nunca porque estás usando un botón de tipo `button`, por lo que el formulario no se envía a ningún sitio, en su lugar se llama a una función que lee los datos del formulario y los envía via AJAX (sin hacer *submit*).

Dos posibles soluciones al problema:

**1. Haz que el formulario se envíe**

Para ello lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente:

1. Cambia el botón de `type="button"` a `type="submit"`. De este modo el formulario se enviará cuando lo pulses.

   ```
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnGuarda">Guardar</button>
   ```
2. Cambia el controlador del click y hazlo una función independiente.

   ```
   function enviarFormulario() {   

       var cargando = $("#carga").html("<center><img class='img-responsive'  src='../imagenes/loading.gif'/><center>");

       $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '../statussol/procesaConfirmada.vbhtml',
           data: $('#enviaConfirmada').serialize(),
           beforeSend: function () {
               $("#muestraFormulario").hide();
               cargando.show().fadeIn();
           },
           success: function (e) {
               cargando.hide();                
               $('#resultado').hide().html("<blockquote style='background: #f9f9f9; border-left: 10px solid #ccc;   margin: 1.5em 10px;  padding: 0.5em 10px;'> <p></p><p style='color:green'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle'></i> ¡ Operación exitosa !</p><p></p> </blockquote>").fadeIn(500);
               $('#resultado').html(e);
           }
       });
   }
   ```
3. Cambia el `action` del formulario para que apunte a la función del punto 2.

   ```
   <form id="enviaConfirmada" name="enviaConfirmada" method="post" action="javascript:enviarFormulario()" class="form-horizontal">
   ```

Ahora que está así, cuando pulses el botón, sí que se enviará el formulario, pero primero ocurrirá la validación del plugin de jQuery y sólo si se valida se llamará a la nueva función que creaste en el paso 2.

**2. Delega el envío al plugin**

Si vas a la documentación del plugin, puedes ver que hay [varios ejemplos](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator/blob/master/demo/ajaxSubmit.html) que muestran como hacer lo que quieres. Para ello lo que tendrías que hacer es añadir otro controlador cuando creas el bootstrapValidator.

Sería algo así (no lo he comprobado, puede que contenga errores):

```
 $('#enviaConfirmada').bootstrapValidator({

     // tu código aquí, no hay necesidad de cambiar nada

 })
 .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
        // Prevén que se mande el formulario
        e.preventDefault();
        // Obtén el formulario
        var $form = $(e.target);
        // Obtén la instancia de bootstrapValidator
        var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');
        // Usa AJAX para enviar el formulario como lo estabas haciendo
        $.post(
            '../statussol/procesaConfirmada.vbhtml', 
            $form.serialize(), 
            function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            }, 
            'json'
         );
    });+
```

> NOTA- Como recomendación personal: deja de usar ese plugin de jQuery (o actualiza a la última versión). Si vas a la [página del proyecto en GitHub](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator), podrás ver que el proyecto ya no está soportado y recomiendan que se usa [FormValidation](http://formvalidation.io/) en su lugar.

Comment: si funciono gracias

Answer (score 1):

Intentas poner a todos tus `inputs` el atributo **[required](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)**.

Ejemplo:

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Puedes tambien validar los campos en blanco antes de serializar el formulario y enviarlo por ajax:

```
$('#btnGuarda').click(function () { 
 $("#enviaConfirmada").find("input").each(function(){
  if($(this).val() == ""){
   alert('Faltan campos por llenar');
   return false;
  }
 });
 var cargando = $("#carga").html("<center><img class='img-responsive'  src='../imagenes/loading.gif'/><center>");

 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '../statussol/procesaConfirmada.vbhtml',
  data: $('#enviaConfirmada').serialize(),
  beforeSend: function () {    
...
...
```

Comment: pasa que estaba usando una libreria de bootstrap para validar campos pero no supe implementarla por lo que lo hare de la forma que comentas

Comment: Es lo recomendable, de hecho puedes usar expresiones regulares en js para que los campos que pides tengan el formato que necesitas, incluso HTML5 tiene los controles input type number, date etc.. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Comment: Drago25 no usa HTML5 sino XHTML 1.0 transicional, por lo que puede que el required no funcione (sería cuestión de que cambiara el doctype)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar usando [jquery.validate.js](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var form = $('#enviaConfirmada');
    form.validate({
        rules:{
            txtNumsolicitud: {
                    required: true, // hay más reglas aplicables
                    maxlength: 10
                }
            },
            otroCampo:{
                    // reglas
                }
            }
    });

    $('#btnGuarda').click(function () {        
        var cargando = $("#carga").html("<center><img class='img-responsive'  src='../imagenes/loading.gif'/><center>");
        if(form.valid()){
            // logica ajax
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loginForm').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {
            $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(result) {
                // The result is a JSON formatted by your back-end
                // I assume the format is as following:
                //  {
                //      valid: true,          // false if the account is not found
                //      username: 'Username', // null if the account is not found
                //  }
                if (result.valid == true || result.valid == 'true') {
                    // You can reload the current location
                    window.location.reload();

                    // Or use Javascript to update your page, such as showing the account name
                    // $('#welcome').html('Hello ' + result.username);
                } else {
                    // The account is not found
                    // Show the errors
                    $('#errors').html('The account is not found').removeClass('hide');

                    // Enable the submit buttons
                    $('#loginForm').bootstrapValidator('disableSubmitButtons', false);
                }
            }, 'json');
        },
        fields: {
            username: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The username is required'
                    }
                }
            },
            password: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The password is required'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Fuente: http://bv.doc.javake.cn/examples/

Answer (score 0):

Para que el elemento label se asocie con el input el nombre del atributo for debe coincidir con el atributo id del input no con el name

como ejemplo el siguiente:

```css
.form-label-input{
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<form action="URL_DONDE_QUIERO_ENVIAR_LO_DATOS">
                                <div class="form-label-input">
                                    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="nombre" name="user_name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-label-input">
                                    <label for="apellido">Apellido:</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="apellido" name="user_last_name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-label-input">
                                    <label for="ciudad">Ciudad:</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="ciudad" name="user_city">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-label-input">
                                    <label for="telefono">Telefono:</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="telefono" name="user_phone_number">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="main_button_form">Realizar Pago</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Mira como se relaciona la etiqueta **label for="nombre"** con la etiqueta **input type="text" id="nombre"** a través del **id "nombre"**